# Mostrar mensaje de validacion HTML5 que salga desde un fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Tengo un formulario con varios campos y necesito que salga un mensaje con HTML5 en el caso que no se cumpla alguna condición entre los campos dentro del fieldset. Este mensaje debe salir desde el fieldset que contiene los campos donde ha surgido el error de validación.

```
<form>

<fieldset>

    Entra primer numero: <input id="n1" type="number" required>

    Entra segundo numero: <input id="n2" type="number" required>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>

    Entra tu nombre: <input id="nombre" type="text" required>

</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

En JavaScript:

```
if (document.getElementById("n1").value > document.getElementById("n2").value ) {
    funcion_con_mensaje_desde_fieldset("El primer numero no debe ser mayor al segundo");
}
```

Comment: "Este mensaje debe salir desde el fieldset" a que te refieres? no me termina de quedar clara tu pregunta

Comment: Si no lo has hecho aún lee https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/fieldset

Comment: @BenderPaisa igual que cuando hay una validación en un campo con required sale un mensaje desde el campo input. En este caso seria igual pero el mensaje sale desde el área del Fieldset

Comment: @Ruben gracias pero no sale información sobre validación con fieldset

Comment: Eso es porque `fieldset` no tiene validación, la validación es una características de `input` y otros elementos de entrada de datos y de `form` pero no es por eso que te sugerí leerlo sino para que si no conoces las características de  `fieldset` las conozcas y ello te ayude a plantear tu pregunta de forma mas clara. Por otro lado quizás un dibujo te ayude a comunicar lo que esperas obtener.

Comment: Quizas me explique mal, lo que pretendo conseguir es que me salga un mensaje de validación como en el input pero en el área de fieldset. ¿ Poniendo un campo oculto input en medio del fieldset y forzar un mensaje con un submit para que salga ? No quiero usar un alert.

Comment: Por "mensaje de validación", ¿te refieres a que haya, dentro del elemento `<fieldset>`, un elemento que tenga un texto en caso de que las condiciones de los elementos `<input>` no se cumplan?

Comment: @CeAlCuadrado podría ser como dices. Pero lo que estaba pensando seria un mensaje que surgiera en el centro del fieldset y sobre este al estilo de los mensajes que salen cuando no se cumple una validación en un input.

Comment: ¿Tienes algo gráfico que permita ilustrar eso que estás buscando? Sería bueno que se pueda agregar a la pregunta, porque tal cual como lo describes, al menos yo no lo logro visualizar.

Comment: @CeAlCuadrado tengo un formulario dividido en  2 fieldset. A la hora de validar cuando hago un submit me debe salir un mensaje de error de validación si lo hay sobre el fieldset y no sobre la caja de texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible mostrar "un mensaje de validación como el input pero en el área de fieldset" entendiendo por mensaje de validación la característica incluida de validación para etiquetas `input` y similares así como para la etiqueta `form` en HTML 5, pero tienes muchas alternativas.

Una alternativa es usar `appendChild` para agregar un nodo con el mensaje correspondiente.

El siguiente ejemplo se agrega el mensaje "Error de validación" al ejecutar.

```js
(function() {
  var e = document.getElementById('miFieldset');
  var miDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
  miDiv.style.color = 'red';
  var mensaje = document.createTextNode('Error de validación');
  miDiv.appendChild(mensaje);
  e.appendChild(miDiv);

})()
```

```html
<fieldset id="miFieldset">
  Nombres: <input type="text"> <br> Apellidos: <input type="text">
</fieldset>
```

Para adaptarlo a tu caso tu función que se haga cargo de la validación deberá agregar el elemento cuando se cumplan las condiciones correspondientes.

Referencias

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/fieldset
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild